# Do I still need a high CRI rating light source when I have a color target?

Tags: colorchecker

I have brought some color targets so I can get accurate color on my shooting. The problem though is that finding a cheap high CRI rating light to light up the target somewhat difficult, as the rating can be falsely advertised by some less known brands.

And that led to my question. If I'm to match my shot to a color target, doesn't it natively fix the problem with low CRI shooting? If a red color came out less saturated because of the non-optimal lighting, using a color target is going to pull the red back up, isn't that a natural fix to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I'm to match my shot to a color target, doesn't it natively fix the problem with low CRI shooting?

No. The problem with CRI is that it is an average value. But you can have a fairly high CRI while also having gaps in the color spectrum. For example, this might be a 95% average CRI but notably lacking in red and blue (I didn't actually do the math). A low CRI bulb could have wavelengths actually missing.

[image]

What you want is a full spectrum/black body light source... something that creates light by burning (sun, incandescent, zenon, etc); even if it has a color bias. Color correction can compensate for a color bias, it cannot make up for a color notch... perhaps "close enough/acceptable"; but not "accurate/true."

A very high CRI average (98%) is also acceptable from a non-black body light source (LED), but they tend to be rare/expensive.

Comment: What is the percentage of the "close enough"? I'll be fine if the target can recover 95% of the original red.

Comment: @reddy, I can't say what CRI would be close enough for your specific color... you would need to measure the color with a spectrophotometer in daylight, and compare that to your result from the camera (because the camera also has non-uniform response).

Comment: But 95% should be pretty easy to achieve... it is much easier/cheaper to use a black body emitter source (e.g. incandescent bulb). These sources often have a color cast/bias, but they have no color notches; and because of that they do not have/need CRI ratings. The color cast in a raw file can easily be removed with white balance corrections; and that would bring the color accuracy *average* to the limits of the camera sensor... probably easily 95% for red. For greater accuracy of a specific channel/color would require manual adjustments at the expense of the unselected colors.

Comment: Will the dollar incandescent bulb from our local store work? I think I need two to evenly lit up the color target, what is a good lumen for this?

Comment: Yes, any typical tungsten/incandescent should do. Assuming you are using a tripod/support the wattage/lumens is not really important. If you need faster shutter speeds (hand holding) then you should get as much power as you reasonably can.

Comment: I just got a Colormunki Photo spectrophotometer, how do I use it to measure the color in daylight? Right now I'm using the "spot measurement" function to measure the color. Or do I even need incandescent light when I have a spectrophotometer?

Comment: The Colormunki spectrophotometer tells you the true color of the sample (and print), it has its' own calibrated light source. It doesn't really do anything to help you *record/reproduce* the color correctly; unless you use it to create a printer profile.

Comment: I wanted to reproduce the color correctly on the screen. I just did some test measurements with the Colormunki, it did pretty well on most color except for brighter color like pink and orange, where it gives the completely wrong color. Another question, does flash works better than incandescent light? I measured my camera flash with Colormunki and it gives like CRI 99 on all spectrum. Would it be better since it works well on all color and the picture came out white while incandescent are orange?

Comment: Flash should not need color (white balance) correction, where most other light sources will.

Comment: @reddy if you are in the U.S. you will not be able to get an incandescent bulb from your local store.  They're illegal now, both to manufacture and to sell.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yup, I went to all local stores around my block and they only sell LED. though I think they only banned incandescent that has low wattage, not all. I also looked up halogen bulbs on amazon as they have equivalent spec as incandescent. But I don't understand why there are no 5000K or 6500K temperature of them, they are all 2700K to 2900K.

Comment: @reddy there's no high temperature halogens because they actually have to run the filament at that temperature to get matching light output.  For the LEDs they can adjust the mix of blue and yellow to get whatever temperature they want.  And I thought halogens were also included in the latest ban, it's based on efficiency ratings and the limit was adjusted to be just beyond what halogens can achieve.

Comment: Incandescent and halogen bulbs are still available in the US as appliance bulbs, plant bulbs (grow lights), flood lights, and other special uses.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, I looked up the regulation details now, they are banning bulbs that produce less than 45 lumens per watt. So a 400 lumen per 29 watt or 14 lumen/watt bulb that I was looking for was banned. Also I have decided to go with flash because of its compact size, since I don't really know where to put the two desk lamps in my room once I'm done.

Comment: update, my equipment arrived and I tested shooting with the two flashes positioned at each side of the target. The result is pretty good, the target was evenly lit without reflection with a nice white color temperature around 6400K. Thanks for the help.